# removing an extension from a FHIR Basic object

Tags: java, hl7-fhir

I am working in Java.

And I am writing tests for the FHIR code that I have just written. I would like to remove an extension from and existing Basic object. I am reading that object from a file, so I could just create another file without out the extension. But the FHIR spec on the [Extensibility](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/extensibility.html) page so helpfully states `"If a system modifies a resource it SHOULD remove any extensions that it does not understand from the modified element and its descendants, because it cannot know whether the modifications it has made might invalidate the value of the unknown extension"` They just don't give any suggestion on how to do that and I have not found a way to do it as I explore the Basic object.

Comment: FHIR objects are just POJOs, right? So removing them should be as simple as iterating over the Extensions and deleting them from the array if they are not recognised. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you @seesharper! I guess I was tired last night when I posted the question!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Extension;
import org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Basic;

List<Extension> extensions = basicObj.getExtension();
extensions.forEach(e -> e.removeExtension());
```

The above does remove all of the extensions from the basicObj.extensions array. However, it also had an effect that I did not expect (because I am still very new to FHIR): all of the extensions descending from the extensions removed above are kept and added to the basicObj.extensions array. I suppose that this is documented behavior and I just have not run across that line yet...